# Gradle + Jenkins: Publishing to other user's directory

Tags: deployment, jenkins, gradle

I'm currently using Jenkins, with Gradle to build the projects. I'm currently trying to use the *uploadArchives* task to place the generated jars under the directory of another user. Currently not having any success:

Jenkins output:

```
[minigame-chronos] $ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/minigame-chronos/gradlew uploadArchives
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:uploadArchives FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/minecraft/server/plugins/minigame-chronos-0.1.jar (Permission denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        name "devServer"
        dirs "/home/minecraft/server/plugins"
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        add project.repositories.devServer
    }
}
```

So far, I've tried experimenting with user groups and the directory permissions.

The directory /home/minecraft/server/plugins/ has been given the following file permissions

```
drw-rw-rw- 2 minecraft minecraft-dev    4096 Jan  4 13:14 plugins
```

Users jenkins and minecraft both exist in the minecraft-dev groups.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "execute" permission for directory - nobody can chdir to it.

try
chmod +x /home/minecraft/server/plugins

@see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: That fixed it! The answer you linked was a very good read :)
Thanks!